# Need to identify this 3-pin Connector to a small amp. It's a Pre-Amp input

Tags: connector, identification, preamp

I could use the neighbouring 3.5mm stereo jack for sound input, but those connections are flimsy.

[image: photo of PCB showing connector]

It's a 3-pin connector, 10mm long, 6mm wide and 7mm high with alignment slots on all sides but the back (see picture).  I could not manage to measure the pins.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please put more effort in depicting or describing the part in question. If you can't do better measurements (e.g. by using a caliper), use a magnifier and try to describe numbers or manufacturer logos printed or embossed on the part.

Comment: There are no markings on it.  The pin pitch is 2.5mm.  Nothing more to add.

Comment: There are a lot of manufacturers making connectors similar to this. They are all incompatible. Best solution is to ask the manufacturer of the board about that issue. We all can only guess. Usually with little outcome.

Comment: I asked the amazon storefront the question...not hopeful that I will get an answer.

Comment: Sure it's not 2.54 mm pin spacing?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the notches in your less than clear picture it appears to be a JST [B3B-XH-A(LF)(SN)](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/B3B-XH-A-LF-SN/455-2248-ND/1651046). 
[image]
You just need to verify pitch in this [Datasheet](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eXH.pdf)., however they seem to match with what you have given.

For a mate you would be looking at [XHP-3](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/XHP-3/455-2219-ND/1651017)

[image]

Digi-Key offers a variety of jumper wires or contacts for that housing depending on the wire gauge you need. Here is a list of options. https://www.digikey.com/short/z3fv52

Answer (score 1):

I call this familly of connector JST but I am not sure this is the real term.
It seems to be the good one until google image or sellers respond to that name.

Comment: I looked at the JST web site, nothing obvious yet.  Still looking.  It's a connector on an XH-M643 amplifier sold on Amazon through the Purfurt storefront.

Comment: it's JST PH or XH depending on the pin spacing. http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=277  http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=199